# How To Utilize Index In Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm not sure if it may even be possible...
I have got a class now, say MyClass:

```
template < typename ... Tn > MyClass;
```

When needed, I have to call the provided function 'get' to access member of a MyClass object:

```
MyClass<int, float, A> obj1;

...

int & i = get<0>(obj1);
A & a = get<2>(obj1);
```

Here is my question: If i plan to make a variadic template 'Outer' and to use it in this form:

```
class C
{
public:
    C(int, float, A);
};
```

--

```
Outer<C> obj2(obj1);
```

The 'Outer':

```
template < typename Ty >
class Outer
{
private:
    Ty inner;

    //template < MyClass >
    Outer(const MyClass<ty ...> & args_packer)
    {
    }
};
```

How can i write that Outer's constructor in variadic template so it can basically do as:

```
    Outer(const MyClass<int, float, A> & args_packer)
        : inner(get<0>(args_packer), get<1>(args_packer), get<2>(args_packer))
    {
    }
```

? What i have to clarify first is that the Outer isn't designed for MyClass only. The MyClass is only for the purpose of debugging Outer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should solve your problem:

`MyClass` seems to act as `std::tuple`, So I use it instead.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

#if 1 // not present in C++11
template<std::size_t... Is> struct index_sequence{};

template<int N, std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence : public make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> {};
#endif

template <typename T>
class Outer
{
public:
    template <typename ... Ts>
    Outer(const std::tuple<Ts ...>& args_packer) :
        Outer(args_packer, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>())
    {
    }

private:
    template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
    Outer(const std::tuple<Ts ...>& args_packer, index_sequence<Is...>) :
        inner(std::get<Is>(args_packer)...)
    {
    }

private:
    T inner;
};
```

Now, let test it:

```
class A{};
class C
{
public:
    C(int, float, A);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple(42, 0.5f, A{});
    Outer<C> out(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my... Thnx & I'l try this later. Happy New Year btw.